# Input и optput не работает на android 10 в чем проблема?

Tags: java, android, input, android-assets, java-output-stream

Мое приложение делает копию файла из assets и помещает на хранилище устройства для дальнейшей работы с ним, однако на androide 10  не работает, и срабатывает исключение выводить сообщение "Ошибка отправки мода"  вот мой код

```
`private void copyAsset(String filename){
    String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/games";
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    if(!dir.exists()){
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = assetManager.open(filename);
        File outFile = new File(dirPath,filename);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        copyFile(in, out);
        // Toast.makeText(this,"пуск!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }catch(IOException e){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Ошибка отправки мода", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }finally {
        if(in != null){
            try {
                in.close();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(out != null){
            try {
                out.close();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer))!= -1){
        out.write(buffer, 0,read);


    }

}`
```

в манифесте я указал все разращения для записи и чтения а также код чтобы просит разращение от пользователя

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORAGE);
                }else{
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORAGE);
                }
            }else{

            }
```

на android 9 работает как надо. Как мне это исправить?

Comment: Если файл необходим только вашему приложению - сохраняйте в папках, выделенных вашему приложению: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific

Comment: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE больше не работает в 10м андроиде. файловое апи работает только в домашнем каталоге приложения начиная с 10го андроида.

Comment: но файл необходим другому приложению